# VBA for loop addition

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a loop that adds odd numbers up to a certain point. How can I get the integer i to go up by 2. I know there is a way, it's something like i by 2, but I don't remember the exact command. If anyone could please help me, I would appreciate it

Comment: Please remember to mark questions as solved if you get a suitable answer, it helps others searching with a similar problem and lets other members know that you don't require further help.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean:

```
For i = 1 To 9 Step 2

Next i
```

Or:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        '// Odd

    End If
Next i
```